# JavaScript: What is the 'typeof' Window

Tags: javascript, object, typeof

I'm actually a little bit confused about the `typeof` Window in JavaScript. I've written a simple code.

```
(function (w) {
  'use strict';

  console.log(typeof Window); // function
  console.log(w.parent); // [object Window]
  console.log(typeof w.parent); // object
})(window);
```

Even if the parent of `w` is `Window`. It's type is `object`. But when I'm operating `typeof` over `Window` itself, it's giving `function`. Why this difference?

I've setup one [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bipvXn?p=preview).

Comment: `w.parent` is an `object` of `Window`, not `Window`(a `constructor`).

Comment: But in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dineshpatra28/bgh9x46z/2/  when I checked its telling object.